# RESTful Post Processing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on creating the ability to send data to a RESTful Rails web service and invoke additional post-processing based on the data that is passed. For example, instapaper.com can take a link and will extract the body content to make it available for offline reading. Is there a best practice for doing structuring this in Rails so that concerns remain separate?

I am somewhat new to rails, am getting used to the conventions, and wanted to ping the community to see how others may structure a problem like this. The controller did not seem like the best place to do this processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would pass the stuff to Delayed_job using functions in lib or in more likely in a model since you're talking about restful processing

Useful link: [therailsway.com/2009/7/22/do-it-later-with-delayed-job](http://therailsway.com/2009/7/22/do-it-later-with-delayed-job)